# Wordpress redirect issue, headers already sent

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, updates

I am wondering, based on the code bellow, where I would want to put my wp_redirect function because where it currently is does nothing but spazzes out and sais:

```
 Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /***/***/WordPress/WordPressDev/wp-includes/script-loader.php:664) in /***/***/WordPress/WordPressDev/wp-includes/pluggable.php on line 881
```

Which I get because the page has already loaded. but I am un sure where to call this function.

I have replace my web site and any "personal data" with stars and example.com. How ever this code does work, it just wont redirect me.

thoughts?

```
function get_latest_version_zip(){
             global $wp_filesystem;

             if(current_user_can('update_themes')){
                $aisis_file_system_structure = WP_Filesystem();
                $aisis_cred_url = 'admin.php?page=aisis-core-update';
                if($aisis_file_system_structure == false){
                    request_filesystem_credentials($aisis_cred_url);
                    $this->credential_check = true;
                }

                $aisis_temp_file_download = download_url( 'http://example.com/aisis/aisis_update/Aisis2.zip' );

                if(is_wp_error($aisis_temp_file_download)){
                    $error = $aisis_temp_file_download->get_error_code();
                    if($error == 'http_no_url') {
                        add_action( 'admin_notices', 'aisis_framework_download_update_erors' );
                    }
                }

                $aisis_unzip_to = $wp_filesystem->wp_content_dir() . "/themes/" . get_option('template');

                $this->delete_contents_check(); //Check if we need to delete the aisis core folder.

                $aisis_do_unzip = unzip_file($aisis_temp_file_download, $aisis_unzip_to);

                unlink($aisis_temp_file_download); //delete temp jazz

                if(is_wp_error($aisis_do_unzip)){
                    $error = $aisis_do_unzip->get_error_code();
                    if($error == 'incompatible_archive') {
                        $this->aisis_incompatible_archive_errors();
                    }
                    if($error == 'empty_archive') {
                        $this->aisis_empty_archive_errors();
                    }
                    if($error == 'mkdir_failed') {
                        $this->aisis_mkdir_failed_errors();
                    }
                    if($error == 'copy_failed') {
                        $this->aisis_copy_failed_errors();
                    }
                    return;
                }
                //throwing errors
                wp_redirect(admin_url('admin.php?page=aisis-core-options'));
                exit;

             }
         }
```

in my functions.php file I placed the following code:

```
 function callback($buffer){
     return $buffer;
 }

 function add_ob_start(){
     ob_start("callback");
 }

 function flush_ob_end(){
     ob_end_flush();
 }

 add_action('wp_head', 'add_ob_start');
 add_action('wp_footer', 'flush_ob_end');
```

with this I still get the error, I think I misunderstanding something....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just replace the following line

```
add_action('wp_head', 'add_ob_start');
```

with

```
add_action('init', 'add_ob_start');
```

Output buffering should start before anything sent/echoed to the browser and `wp_head` hook occurs a bit later than `init` hook and till then headers already sent and also Keep/place it at the top of your `functions.php` before anything echoed/sent to the browser.

Comment: headers already sent by (output started at /***/***/WordPress/WordPressDev/wp-includes/script-loader.php:664) in /***/***/WordPress/WordPressDev/wp-includes/pluggable.php on line 881

Comment: To be honest I'm using same code in my WordPress site and it's working fine. I just used `init` hook instead of `wp_head`.

Comment: using 'init' stopped the error but the code did not run.

Answer (score 1):

Another possibility would be adding a priotity:

```
add_action('wp_head', 'add_ob_start', 1);
```

The third param is $priority.

Also, if you're hooking in more than one function, it gives you complete control of the execution chain.

Comment: This answer should have a lot more upvotes. I realize its 10 years old... but aged well. You will want a priority, especially if you are checking things like IDK post id's or post formats or templates. You will want it to be ran with that priority, otherwise it will give the error.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that somewhere in wordpress the `header()` function has been called and some output was already sent to the client while `output buffering` is off.

Headers have to be sent before any output, otherwise you get the error you described.

```
wp_redirect(admin_url('admin.php?page=aisis-core-options'));
```

The above line sets a header like this: `header('Location: admin.php......');`

Turning on output buffering via php.ini, at the index.php of wordpress or simply before anything is echo'ed to the client should take care of the error.

Details/Documentation can be found here: http://php.net/manual/en/book.outcontrol.php

simplest way i can think of is make your wordpress index.php look like this:

```
ob_start();
// content of your index.php here
ob_flush();
```

Comment: when you say my WordPress index file, which done do you mean? the core?, the one in the themes directory, or the one my theme? there's lots of WP index files from what I know.

Comment: the entry point from what I understand is the theme index.php, so I will test this and report back

Comment: that did not work. The only other place I can think is the WordPress core files, but since those get updated when you update WordPress you know not to touch those

Comment: http://www.dagondesign.com/articles/wordpress-hook-for-entire-page-using-output-buffering/

Comment: Can you explain this peaice as to what I am suppose to do with it? or if I need it in my case

function callback($buffer) {
  // modify buffer here, and then return the updated code
  return $buffer;
}

Comment: just use it without the comment.. it would let you modify the output of the website before it gets sent to the client

Comment: so I don't actually have to populate the method with anything? because from i'm reading I would call that method and pass my redirect into it as $buffer, so callback(wp_redirect('take me to jail'));

Comment: it is already populated with return $buffer.  all you want to do is enable `output buffering`. don't make it more complicated than it has to be.

Comment: Ok, So I did as the article suggests, see the code above and I still seem to fail at life....why is this not working?

Comment: because output buffering is still not working. try enabling it via the php.ini - signing off for now, good luck!

Comment: this is turning into not the answer I wanted as most people will not have output buffering turned on.....especially on shared hosting or even on private....

Comment: would you rather find where exactly in wordpress the output is echoed? again.. all you want to do is turn output buffering on before any output is given and flush it after all headers are sent. you can also try to add your code before anything is echoed to the browser. the article i pasted seems to be useful for others so you are probably doing something wrong. time to start thinking for yourself (at least a bit). good night!

Comment: ok well i double checked and mine is set to 4086, sorry to question you. I was just curious. so now I wonder why it doesnt work....