# Do most Wordpress users have output_buffering On?

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

My question is in relation to the answer to my other question seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12608881/wordpress-redirect-issue-headers-already-sent) - now most developers and designers who work with the php back end and the guts of the code will have this turned on or should....I think

But does the average user, using my theme, or any other theme on WordPress have this turned on? do most private or shared hosting services have this turned on?

Comment: I would add your callbacks to something that doesn't get called after output has started. Won't have to worry about it that way. If needed, split up your function into two that get called at separate times.

Comment: i dont think I follow. any ways thats not my main question but I did some research and found out that it is on by default.

Comment: I was commenting on the underlying problem you were facing in your other question -- needing to be able to redirect under certain conditions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is. its set to a value, and because of that - it means its on. with out it I think there would be issues